# VS installer project: DotNet6 installation always starts behind setup window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, installation, project

I added a Visual Studio Installer project to my WPF project. It all works fine so far, but there is one thing driving me crazy during installation on a target system.
When I start the setup.exe on destination machine, it automatically launches the installation of windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.18-win-x64.exe as defined in the project. But the DotNet installation window reproducable starts behind the main installer window.

Is there any simple solution to make it top most, so even unexperienced users will recognize it?